# Why doesn't joining multiple MySQL queries with semicolons work with Perl DBI?

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I would like to insert values into two separate MySQL tables using [DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI). I tried to combine two working `INSERT` queries into one by inserting a `;` between them:

```
$dbh->do(q{
    INSERT INTO `testA`(test) values('testvalue111');
    INSERT INTO `testB`(test) values('testvalue222');
});
```

But I always get an error:

> Syntactic error in "INSERT INTO `testB`(test) values('testvalue222 ..."

If I separate the queries into two separate `do` calls, it works. But the combined query works fine in phpMyAdmin. Why does it fail in Perl?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set an option in the `connect` call to enable this. From [the docs](http://search.cpan.org/~capttofu/DBD-mysql-4.022/lib/DBD/mysql.pm):

> `mysql_multi_statements`
>   As of MySQL 4.1, support for multiple statements seperated by a semicolon (;) may be enabled by using this option. Enabling this option may cause problems if server-side prepared statements are also enabled.

It is disabled by default, and should probably remain unset - that's a large avenue for SQL injection (which you should be reading about especially if you're not using binds).

Comment: It is better, however, to use separate calls to ease readability.

Comment: Combining calls makes sence in order to improve the performance, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By default, DBD::mysql doesn't allow you to execute multiple statements at once. Although you *can* enable this with the `mysql_multi_statements` option as [Mat showed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13333281), you shouldn't do that: among other things, your code will be less portable because some database drivers don't have any such option, and it can cause issues with prepared statements.

Instead, just issue a separate DBI command for each statement.

Answer (score -2):

INSERT INTO `testA`(test) values('testvalue111'),('testvalue222');

Comment: Skip is inserting into two different tables.