# Multi-line MySQL in Perl

Tags: mysql, perl

I am trying to pass a command to my database (MariaDB/MySQLi) but Perl's DBI is giving me an error, whatever I try. The thing is that I can execute the MySQL fine in phpMyAdmin without fault. The error that I receive is:

> DBD::mysql::st execute failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for
>   the right syntax to use near `SELECT DISTINCT t.bf FROM wrpec t JOIN wrpec r ON t.path LIKE r.path || '%'` at line 2 at
>   retrieve-includes.pl line 20.
>
> DBD::mysql::st fetchrow_array failed:
>   `fetch()` without `execute()` at retrieve-includes.pl line 22.

The full test file (fake database obviously) is as below.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;
use Data::Dumper;

my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=mydatabase;host=machine";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, 'root', '') or die "Couldn't connect to database: " . DBI->errstr;;

my $request_includes = "
SET sql_mode = PIPES_AS_CONCAT;
SELECT DISTINCT t.bf
FROM `wrpec` t
JOIN `wrpec` r
ON t.path LIKE r.path || '%'
WHERE r.bf = 'WRPECsmain\%hd' AND t.has_tree;";

my $sth = $dbh->prepare($request_includes) or die "Couldn't prepare statement: " . $dbh->errstr;
$sth->execute();

while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
   print Dumper(\@row);
}

$sth->finish();
```

I have also tried some ideas I found online: using a clean-up sub that replaces all white-space characters by hard spaces to make sure you're passing a string, and I also tried this notation (I forgot the name) but it doesn't work either (same error).

```
my $request_includes = <<"REQUEST_INCLUDES";

SET sql_mode = PIPES_AS_CONCAT;
SELECT DISTINCT t.bf
FROM `wrpec` t
JOIN `wrpec` r
ON t.path LIKE r.path || '%'
WHERE r.bf = 'WRPECsmain\%hd' AND t.has_tree;
REQUEST_INCLUDES
```

Comment: If you don't need interpolation, don't use double quotes. In your HEREDOC, you can do `<<'REQUEST_INCLUDES'` with single quotes `''`. In any case, you do not need to escape the percent sign `\%`, because Perl never interpolates hashes. There is no sane way to do that because they are not ordered. Also, it would break `sprintf`. :)

Comment: I never  seen ||  in mysql .. are you sure of this  ?

Comment: Re. the duplicate: don't enable the option given in the accepted answer. I'm writing a new answer about the correct way to do this.

Comment: @scaisEdge you're right. They might already be able to execute more than one query. Can you even join with a `like`?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot if you think that's not the right answer, why did you vtc? It looked correct at first glance, but I think I'll hammer-reopen it because there is also wrong SQL syntax in the question.

Comment: Because the issue is the same in both questions. We don't need two questions asking the same thing. That's the whole point of duplicates.

Comment: @scaisEdge @simbabque It is valid, given the self-explanatory flag `SET sql_mode = PIPES_AS_CONCAT;` [Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pipes_as_concat). Don't be too quick to judge! As I said, this works when thrown in phpMyAdmin, it just doesn't work when pushing through DBI.

Comment: Removing the flag, and going with the original sql alternative solves the problem. This is a shame because I was trying to create a script that works on MySQL as wel as PostgreSQL without changes.

Comment: Have you tried to send the `SET sql_mode = PIPES_AS_CONCAT;` as a seperate statement?

Comment: As @dgw says, that should then solve the problem. You can `$dbh->do('SET sql_mode PIPES_AS_CONCAT');` before. If you truly want to have support for two different engines, maybe DBIC is a better approach?

Comment: Try as @dgw & @ simababque has commented, I think you won't be able to execute 2 different type of statement, One is just Mysql command while the other one you trying to retrieve the data.

Comment: What's wrong with `CONCAT(r.path, '%')`? PostgreSQL has a `CONCAT` function; it just has a fancy non-standard operator as well, and it's better to avoid confusing others who read your code.

Comment: Tip: You should always use [`RaiseError`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#RaiseError)

Comment: @Borodin Unfortunately, it's off by default. :(

Comment: @Borodin I figured that out now as well. I was led to believe that PostgreSQL and MySQL only have different concatenating functions. That's a fault on my side.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: You're right. I was certain it defaulted to on! Ah well, I guess I was thinking of `PrintError`. Thanks for saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a SQL syntax error because by default, [DBD::mysql doesn't allow you to execute multiple statements at once](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13333230). You should run two separate DBI commands instead:

```
$dbh->do( q{SET sql_mode = 'PIPES_AS_CONCAT'} );

my $sth = $dbh->prepare(q{
    SELECT DISTINCT t.bf
    FROM `wrpec` t
    JOIN `wrpec` r
    ON t.path LIKE r.path || '%'
    WHERE r.bf = 'WRPECsmain\%hd' AND t.has_tree
});
```

---

> I was trying to create a script that works on MySQL as wel as PostgreSQL without changes.

Enable MySQL's [ANSI mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi) and double quote your identifiers:

```
$dbh->do( q{SET sql_mode = 'ANSI'} ) if $mysql;

my $sth = $dbh->prepare(q{
    SELECT DISTINCT t.bf
    FROM "wrpec" t
    JOIN "wrpec" r
    ON t.path LIKE r.path || '%'
    WHERE r.bf = 'WRPECsmain\%hd' AND t.has_tree
});
```

There are a couple other issues, though:

- unescaped `_` and `%` in `r.path` will be interpreted as wildcards
- `'foo' LIKE 'foo%'` is true

To only fetch rows where the `t.path` is a prefix of `r.path`, but they're not equal, do:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT t.bf
FROM "wrpec" t
JOIN "wrpec" r
  ON POSITION(t.path IN r.path) = 1
  AND t.path != r.path
WHERE r.bf = 'WRPECsmain\%hd'
  AND t.has_tree
```

Comment: Are sure about the need for escaping characters? Because I am now looking at direct input into phpMyAdmin's MySQL, and `WRPECsmain%hd` matches `WRPECsmain%hd` literally, whereas `WRPECsmain\%hd` does not. It seems as if escaping is not necessary? Or is this only necessary when working in ANSI mode? In your example code you have a boolean variable `$mysql`. How do you create this?

Comment: Escaping is necessary on the RHS of `LIKE`, regardless of the SQL mode. How `$mysql` gets set is up to you; to work with either a MySQL or a Postgres database, you'll need a different DSN and connection options anyway. I would recommend storing your MySQL credentials in an [option file](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html) and your Postgres credentials in [.pgpass](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/libpq-pgpass.html).

Comment: Users of your script could specify the configuration details (like the path to their MySQL options file) in a config file.

Comment: Yes, the RHS of LIKE but not in the subsequent WHERE class though? As I said, it only works if you do NOT escape.

Comment: I just said wildcards have to be escaped in `r.path`, which isn't used in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @BramVanroy Oh, you must be talking about `r.bf = 'WRPECsmain\%hd'`...I assumed you wanted to match literal backslash, literal percent sign. If not, you need to do `r.bf = 'WRPECsmain%hd'`.